# Updating properties of a Django model on save with processing of submitted ImageFields

Tags: django, django-models, signals, django-orm, imagefield

Basically I'm trying to save a Django model which contains an `ImageField`, and updates its `latitude` and `longitude` FloatFields with values grabbed from the EXIF data contained in the image, if any.

Here's a sample model illustrating the issue:

```
class GeoImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='/path/to/uploads')
    latitude = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    longitude = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self):
        # grab the path of the image of the ImageField
        # parse the EXIF data, fetch latitude and longitude
        self.latitude = fetched_latitude
        self.longitude = fetched_longitude
        return super(GeoImage, self).save()
```

Can you spot the problem? I don't know how to access the image filepath before the model instance is actually saved, and I can't save the record, update some properties then save it back again, because it would create a post_save loop (and same goes theorically with a `post_save` signal…

Any help much appreciated.

**Note:** I don't need help with EXIF data extraction nor parsing, just with the way to update the whole model on save().

**Edit:** Okay so you can access the file object and process it further before the record being saved:

```
class GeoImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='/path/to/uploads')
    latitude = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    longitude = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self):
        latitude, longitude = gps_utils.process_exif(self.image.file)
        if latitude: self.latitude = latitude
        if longitude: self.longitude = longitude
        return super(GeoImage, self).save(*args, **kwarg)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FileField should return a file-like object that you can read to extract exif information.

Comment: Indeed! For the records, I edited the question to reflect a possible implementation.